# Selected checkbox value uses ajax to repopulate select

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, coldfusion

My form has checkboxes with user roles, and a select box with users. I need a select box to repopulate based on the checkbox value(s) when clicked. The checkboxes allow selection of either "all" (in which case the select options need not change) OR any combination of "cm", "adv", "cd" values.
Once the checkbox(es) get clicked, the select box should repopulate dynamically (all this before form gets submitted).

```
<cfquery datasource="datasourceName" name="qry_staff">
  SELECT userID, lastname + ', ' + firstname AS staffName
  FROM   userTable
  WHERE  role IN('cm','adv','cd')
</cfquery>

<form>
  <input type="checkbox" name="assignedRole" id="checkedAll" value="all">All<BR>
  <input type="checkbox" name="assignedRole" id="assignedRole" value="cm" class="checkSingle">Case managers<BR>
  <input type="checkbox" name="assignedRole" id="assignedRole" value="adv" class="checkSingle">Advisors<BR>
  <input type="checkbox" name="assignedRole" id="assignedRole" value="cd" class="checkSingle">Career developers

  <select name="staff>
    <cfloop query="qry_staff" multiple="multiple">
      <cfoutput>
        <option value="#qry_staff.userID#">#qry_staff.staffName#</option>
      </cfoutput>
    </cfloop>
  </select>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

I don't want the entire page to reload every time a user changes text box selection(s). I haven't been able to find a suitable solution, and am in an intense time crunch. I'm jquery knowledgeable, but not Ajax. What I've been able to find makes me think Ajax would really be the way to go here, but would be thrilled to use jquery if possible. I'd greatly appreciate help with an example of how to accomplish this, using code supplied here.

Comment: Your google search string is, `coldfusion jquery ajax example`.  Had you thought of that earlier, you might have found a appropriate solution in less time than it took to type your question.

Comment: I found a solution that works if assignedRole only passes in one value. I have yet to find one that accommodates what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

change your main page to this.

```
<form>
    <input type="checkbox" name="assignedRole" id="checkedAll" value="all">All<BR>
    <input type="checkbox" name="assignedRole" id="assignedRole" value="cm" class="checkSingle">Case managers<BR>
    <input type="checkbox" name="assignedRole" id="assignedRole" value="adv" class="checkSingle">Advisors<BR>
    <input type="checkbox" name="assignedRole" id="assignedRole" value="cd" class="checkSingle">Career developers

    <select name="staff"></select>
    <input type="submit">
</form>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".checkSingle").change(function(){
            $.getJSON("thecall.cfm?",{assignedRole: $(this).val(), ajax: 'true'}, function(j){
            var options = '';
            for (var i = 0; i < j.length; i++) {
                options += '<option value="' + j[i].optionValue + '">' + j[i].optionDisplay + '</option>';
                }
                $("select#staff").html(options).change();
            });
        }).change();
    });
</script>
```

make a separate file called thecall.cfm

```
<cfset return_struct = StructNew() />
<cfquery datasource="datasourceName" name="qry_staff">
  SELECT userID, lastname + ', ' + firstname AS staffName
  FROM   userTable
  WHERE  role = '#form.assignedRole#'
</cfquery>


<cfset data = [] /> 

<cfoutput query="qry_staff">
  <cfset obj = {"optionValue" = userID, "optionDisplay" = staffName} />
  <cfset arrayappend(data, obj) />
</cfoutput>
<cfoutput>#serializeJSON(data)# </cfoutput>
```

Comment: If theCall.cfm is going to be called by ajax, won't `#form.assignedRole#'` be undefined?

Comment: Correct, the main page errors on load, with a message that #form.assignedRole# is undefined in FORM.

Comment: yes, sorry you're right, should be #url.assignedRole#